# Assign a value for specific words in certain rows, then add - seen 500 recommendations, but missing something. Please help asap

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let me start by saying yes, I searched lots of posts before making this one, BUT they either had me lost or wouldnt be exactly what I need.  :(  (And yes, its been many years since I've done this, so I'm like a fresh beginner. Sorry.)

I need to know how to accomplish this in excel. I've searched & searched, but not really found any solution for it (which I figure it should be simple). I thought a simple one ought to work, like an IF formula, but couldnt get it quite right for this....

****This would be a perfect, but if too detailed, I'm very flexible****
I need to know how to accomplish this in excel. I've searched & searched, but not really found any solution for it (which I figure it should be simple). I tried IF formula, but couldnt get it quite right for this. It's been a long long time since I've done much on excel, so I'm back at beginner knowledge, lol

```
Row 10 - If under 900 then give a hidden value of -1 point. If 901-1050 = 1 point. If above 1050 = 3 points
Row 12 - If 1.5 or more, I want it to have a value of 1
Row 13 - If "yes" = value of 2 points (no or blank doesnt have any value)
Row 17 - If "Yes" = 4 points
Row 22 (if this is easily possible) - "yes" = -2 points
Row 26 - "yes" = 4 points
Row 27 - yes = 2 points
... Then last Row I want it to give sum of all that column's value total
```

NOTE: If it is harder to make it assign the negative (-1) values too, then I just wont assign them any value.
If blank or No entered any of the cells, dont assign any points, just ignore it.

[Screenshot of excel page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drWAi.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your recent attempts by editing your question?

Comment: What IF commands have you used and why don't they work?

Comment: You are right each of your rows should have an `IF` formula except the last row would use the `SUM` formula adding the results of all your ifs. UNLESS you want your last row to have all your ifs with pluses inbetween to add them up. Example row 22 could use a formula like `IF(A22="YES",-2,0)` (assuming A22 is where the data is).

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways to approach this:

1. You simply write a single (though it will feel long and therefore evil) formula in the "score" cell for each column. That formula would have a component for each of the "hidden" scores for the desired features and sum up the results.

Or,

2. Make a `Named Range` for each of the items you want to have a "hidden" value for and give each its appropriate formula. Then the "score" cell has a formula that adds or sums them all up.

So, first let's look at the second way. *(Your description indicating which rows get what scores is... broken... as the rows indicated clearly are not all correct any longer. Row 26 is the most obvious example as it has no characteristic in Column1 and so seems extremely unlikely to get a "yes" in any column. So I'm guessing when I give the names below. I will use the row numbers in the sheet image, not the ones in your description.*

Create the `Named Ranges`, one for each row, so seven of them. Give them meaningful names, like `Size`, `Bathrooms`, `Townhouse`, `UtilitiesIncluded`, `PetRestrictions`, `HasWasherDryer`, and `Hookups`. Then put the following formulas in each's `Refers to` formula area:

**VERY IMPORTANT:  All the following formulas are written using column B references. Be SURE the selected cell on the sheet is in column B, any row but for sure column B, when you enter the formulas into each `Named Range`'s `Refers to:` formula bar.**

Size:  `=IFS(B$10<=900,-1,B$10<=1050,1,TRUE,3)`

Bathrooms:  `=IF(B$13>=1.5,1,0)`

Townhouse:  `=IF(B$14="YES",2,0)`

UtilitiesIncluded:  `=IF(B$18="YES",4,0)`

PetRestrictions:  `=IF(B$23="YES",-2,0)`

HasWasherDryer:  `=IF(B$27="YES",4,0)`

Hookups:  `=IF(B$28="YES",2,0)`

And for the summation cell ("score" cell), just add them up:

```
=Size + Bathrooms + Townhouse + UtilitiesIncluded + PetRestrictions + HasWasherDryer + Hookups
```

Or,

```
=SUM(Size,Bathrooms,Townhouse,UtilitiesIncluded,PetRestrictions,HasWasherDryer,Hookups)
```

However, if I am picking the characteristics correctly, the last two are a bit mutually exclusive. If there is a washer/dryer combo present, there are surely hookups, but also surely, you won't want "6" for a total (4 + 2 = 6...). Seems likely you'd want just the "4" from that line and no contribution from the "W/D Hookups" line. If so, one could do a hard solution writing a formula for that line that considers first the existence of the appliances, then if none, gives a "2" and if there are the appliances, gives a "0"... But again, that's harder than need be.

You could instead give actually having the appliances a "2" and let the hookups line score "2" more for a total of the desired "4" and if not present, a zero is contributed letting the hookups line then stand for itself. In doing so you keep the very simple single test formulas.

If a total of "6" is actually desired, or I have guessed the lines wrongly, just leave it as above. So change the "4" to a "2" or leave it be as above, depending upon your actual desire here.

Since you are beginning again, I'll take a moment for two "learning" things:

1. Notice the `$` character before each row number in the formulas. By being there, the formula will be locked to the row, but since the column label (`B` for the above formulas) does not have one before it, the cells looked at change if you use the `Named Range` name in a different column's formula. So you need only one set of `Named Ranges` instead of one for every column. Use it in column D and the rows stay the same, but the cells looked at will all be in column D.

However, that would all fail if you selected a cell in some other column and then entered all the formulas. Because the column label doesn't have one, the formula would be rather different. Won't get into examples, but it would be failure, pure and simple.

If the rows did not have the `$`'s, you'd have to select each cell before entering each Name's formula. But the do, so you just have to be in the column, not in particular cells. That's actually a BIG help.

2. The `IFS` formula for `Size` is simple, just two tests and the default. So it is pretty easy to read as shown. However, those things can have lots of tests, not just two or three. Then laying them out in the formula bar like this:

   =IFS(B$10<=900,-1,
           B$10<=1050,1,
           TRUE,3)

can help you see them clearly a year from now when you want to change something.

So, how would you implement the first approach, that of putting this all into the single total "score" cell? Just place the formulas for each one into a single formula with `+` between each piece. All the same logic, but instead of being in `Named Ranges` the formulas are in that single cell. The only downside is they may blend with each other when trying to follow your work in three years when looking for a new apartment again. But no other downside. Some people hate `Named Ranges` and would like this way just to avoid them. Whatever works best for your own self as this is clearly for you, not a crowd of users.

(I have removed the part about the `LET` function since the site considers it to be Spam.)